# Jar file can run from Gradle Run but got NoClassDefFoundError when running within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

I built a jar file using Gradle.  It was running fine from "gradle run", but when I ran it from within Eclipse (Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations), I got NoClassDefFoundError on one of the Spring classes.

This is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.ii.mainClass'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

jar {
     manifest {
         attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.ii.mainClass'
    }
 }
 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 targetCompatibility = 1.7

 dependencies {
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework.xd:spring-xd-tuple:1.0.4.RELEASE'
   }
```

I looked at the jar file, it doesn't have the dependent jars, that's why I got NoClassDefinition error when running within Eclipse.  I also tried this by including these jars locally, but this doesn't solve the problem, can someone let me know how to make this run within Eclipse?

```
  dependencies {   
       compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you add dependencies to your build.gradle, you need to `gradle eclipse` from the command line to get the new JARs into the .classpath that is the eclipse project configuration.  If you've got eclipse running while you do this, you need to refresh the project and you'll see the new dependencies show up.  There is probably a plug-in for eclipse or something that allows you to do this whole dance in the IDE.